# Prevent subtract item price to total amount when quantity is less than one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I prevent to subtract the item price when the quantity of the item is less than one? I have a reducer where I have an action where the user can control the quantity of the item by simply clicking the increase and decrease button. What I want to achieve is, if the quantity of the item is 1 then the price of the item will not subtract to the total amount of the cart.

```
if (action.type === "UPDATE_ITEM_QUANTITY") {
  let totalAmount;

  const tempCart = state.items.map(item => {
    if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
      if (action.payload.type === "increment") {
        let newQuantity = item.quantity + 1;
        totalAmount = state.totalAmount + item.price;
        return { ...item, quantity: newQuantity };
      }

      if (action.payload.type === "decrement") {
        let newQuantity = item.quantity - 1;
        if (newQuantity < 1) newQuantity = 1;
        totalAmount = state.totalAmount - item.price;
        return { ...item, quantity: newQuantity };
      }
    }

    return item;
  });

  return { ...state, items: tempCart, totalAmount: totalAmount };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your subtract logic under the condition. Or just prevent this action to proceed if item.quantity will became less then 1

```
if (action.payload.type === "decrement" && item.quantity - 1 >= 1) {
        let newQuantity = item.quantity - 1;
        totalAmount = state.totalAmount - item.price;
        return { ...item, quantity: newQuantity };
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! But it keeps subtracting the item price to the total amount when I click the decrease button when the quantity is 1.

Comment: If you update your code I'll try to help you